# Invalid product

Tags: ios, xamarin, nutiteq

I'm trying to get the hellomap demo working in Xamarin Studio but I get an error in the logs:

Nov 22 16:51:18  hellomap-ios[611] : MapView: Build time: Oct 19 2015 23:27:17
Nov 22 16:51:18  hellomap-ios[611] : LicenseUtils::CheckLicense: Invalid product

The license key is correct and the bundle identifier as well. Any ideas what went wrong? It worked before, but now I regenerated the license key not anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that your app is with Plaform: **Xamarin iOS**. Most common mistake is to select just iOS and this gives your error message. You need Starter or Pro package for that.

Comment: That was it. What confused me that it did show me maptiles for a few test when starting to test the library. Thanks!